# The type or namespace name "PeterO" could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, cbor

I am just giving a try at utilizing https://github.com/peteroupc/CBOR repo with demo ***hello.cs*** program. But I end up with the following issues.

**1) Attribute *PeterO.Cbor* is not reflecting as others in color. Please refer to the below code.**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PeterO;
using PeterO.Cbor;  // Why this attribute is in different color?

namespace Hello
{
    public class HelloWorld
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
            var cbor1 = CBORObject.NewMap()
               .Add("item", "any string")
               .Add("number", 42)
               .Add("map", CBORObject.NewMap().Add("number", 42))
               .Add("array", CBORObject.NewArray().Add(999f).Add("xyz"))
               .Add("bytes", new byte[] { 0, 1, 2 });
            // The following converts the map to CBOR
            byte[] bytes = cbor1.EncodeToBytes();
            // The following converts the map to JSON
            string json = cbor1.ToJSONString();
            System.Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**2) Error during execution of hello.cs program. Please find the same from the below snapshot.**

Command Used: `mcs hello.cs -out:hello`

Compilation Error Output Msg:

```
hello.cs(8,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `PeterO' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

**Additional Info:**

**1) Dotnet-sdk and Visual Studio Code installation steps are followed as below:**

```
Dotnet-sdk installation steps:
    a) wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/f01e3d97-c1c3-4635-bc77-0c893be36820/6ec6acabc22468c6cc68b61625b14a7d/dotnet-sdk-3.1.402-linux-x64.tar.gz
    b) mkdir -p $HOME/dotnet && tar zxf dotnet-sdk-3.1.402-linux-x64.tar.gz -C $HOME/dotnet
    c) export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
    d) export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet

Visual Studio Code installation steps:
    a) wget https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/2af051012b66169dde0c4dfae3f5ef48f787ff69/code_1.49.3-1601661857_amd64.deb
    b) sudo dpkg -i code_1.49.3-1601661857_amd64.deb && sudo apt-get update
```

**2) Ubuntu, Dotnet, and Visual Studio Code version details:**

```
a) Ubuntu Command: lsb_release -a

Output:
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
    Release:    18.04
    Codename:   bionic
```

```
b) Dotnet Command: dotnet --info

Output:
    .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
     Version:   3.1.402
     Commit:    9b5de826fd

    Runtime Environment:
     OS Name:     ubuntu
     OS Version:  18.04
     OS Platform: Linux
     RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64
     Base Path:   /home/$USER/dotnet/sdk/3.1.402/

    Host (useful for support):
      Version: 3.1.8
      Commit:  9c1330dedd

    .NET Core SDKs installed:
      3.1.402 [/home/$USER/dotnet/sdk]

    .NET Core runtimes installed:
      Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.8 [/home/$USER/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.8 [/home/$USER/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

    To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

```
c) Visual Studio Code details:

    Version: 1.49.3
    Commit: 2af051012b66169dde0c4dfae3f5ef48f787ff69
    Date: 2020-10-02T17:56:11.027Z
    Electron: 9.2.1
    Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
    Node.js: 12.14.1
    V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
    OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-48-generic
```

**3) Dotnet restore command output:**

```
Path: /path/to/repo/CBOR/
Command: dotnet restore
Output: 
    Determining projects to restore...
    /path/to/repo/CBOR/CBOR.csproj : error NU1108: Cycle detected.  [/path/to/repo/CBOR.sln]
    /path/to/repo/CBOR/CBOR.csproj : error NU1108:   PeterO.Cbor -> PeterO.Cbor (>= 4.2.0). [/path/to/repo/CBOR.sln]
```

So, I replaced the **PackageId PeterO.Cbor** with **PackageId Peter Cbor** inside a file /path/to/repo/CBOR/CBOR.csproj. Then it gave the build output as below.

```
Path: /path/to/repo/CBOR/
Command: dotnet restore
Output:
    Determining projects to restore...  Restored 
    /path/to/repo/CBOR/CBOR.csproj (in 306 ms).
    Restored /path/to/repo/CBORTest/CBORTest.csproj (in 319 ms).
    6 of 8 projects are up-to-date for restore.
```

I am very new to the visual studio code and dotnet framework as well.

Could anyone please correct me on this issue and let me know where I went wrong.

Comment: Have you actually added a reference to `Peter0` to your project? A screenshot of your references might be useful.

Comment: Did you do https://github.com/peteroupc/CBOR#how-to-install ?

Comment: It's called a "`using` *directive*". C# has a *completely different feature* called [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/), so it's best not to confuse the names.

Comment: @mjwills I already installed the `PeterO.Cbor` package using nuget packet manager. After installing only, I end up with the mentioned error.

Comment: @WSC Can you please refer all reference points in the link https://github.com/peteroupc/CBOR/blob/master/CBOR/CBOR.csproj

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you've asked before and that one got close too (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266887/the-type-or-namespace-name-petero-could-not-be-found)

Comment: Please don't. I closed it because it doesn't allow me to re-open it after improvising my question back again. @PeterBons

Answer (score 1):

**1:**
That's not an attribute, it's called a [using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) and it's essential the same as `import` in Java, Python (and maybe more) and comparable to a `#include` in C/C++. [Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) are something entirely different in C#.

**2:**
`mcs` is the Mono C# compiler and has nothing to do with .NET. Instead use the [dotnet cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/) to [run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run), [restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore), [build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) and whole lot more.

---

Now, your entire question is kind of confusing, so I'll go step by step showing you how to do what you want.

1. Create a new project

```
dotnet new console --name YourProjectName
```

This will create a new directory `YourProjectName` and place everything you need inside it. Namely, a `YourProjectName.csproj` file and a `Program.cs` file. The `Program.cs` is simply a convention, your entry point (`Main` method) can lie anywhere.

2. Add the CBOR package
   CBOR is available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PeterO.Cbor), meaning we can simply run

```
dotnet add package PeterO.Cbor --version 4.2.0
```

And this will do everything we need it to do. Under the hood this will add

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="PeterO.Cbor" Version="4.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to your `YourProjectName.csproj` file and restore (download/ build any dependencies) of of your project.

3. Now edit `Program.cs`
   Now you can open VS Code (or any text editor) and edit `Program.cs` to do what you want. If you want to test out your program, simply switch to the terminal, `cd` to the directory of your project and run `dotnet run`. This will compile and run your project.

---

**P.S:** I highly recommend following the advice given in [C# programming with Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) guide

Comment: Creating a new project and installing cbor using nuget cli works fine. Thanks.

 `dotnet new console --name YourProjectName;
dotnet add package PeterO.Cbor --version 4.2.0;
dotnet restore;
dotnet run;`

But, I want to integrate the cbor with the fiddler tool where it works with mono. How can I do this?

Comment: If I try to run the command `mcs Program.cs -out:exe`, I am getting the error as ```Program.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `PeterO' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings```

Comment: Well, then you'll need to build your application with mono not dotnet. But that's easy enough, as you can simply use the `msbuild` command to build your `.csproj` project. If you want to use it as a fiddler extension, you'll need to follow [their](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Extend-Fiddler/UseDotNetInFiddlerScript) guide.

Comment: Don't use `mcs` directly, use a build system (`msbuild`), else you'll need to specify all the dependencies and everything manually yourself, similar to having to specify all the linker args manually when building a C/C++ project